# MySQL "between" clause not inclusive?

Tags: sql, mysql, between

If I run a query with a `between` clause, it seems to exclude the ending value.
For example:

```
select * from person where dob between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'
```

This gets all results with `dob` from '2011-01-01' till '2011-01-30'; skipping records where `dob` is '2011-01-31'. Can anyone explain why this query behaves this way, and how I could modify it to include records where `dob` is '2011-01-31'? (without adding 1 to the ending date because its been selected by the users.)

Comment: Nope. I my MySQL installation (version?) `BETWEEN` is inclusive for both values. I have `MySQL Server 5.7` on Windows 10.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The field `dob` probably has a time component.

To truncate it out:

```
select * from person 
where CAST(dob AS DATE) between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'
```

Comment: Instead of `CAST(dob AS DATE)` you can use the more succinct `DATE(dob)`.

Comment: While this works, you'll get better performance by using `>=` and `<` instead of `between`.

Comment: You will get better performance by using `dob BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-01-31 23:59:59`. This is because `DATE(dob)` has to calculate a value for each row and cannot use any indexes on that field.

Comment: @joshuahedlund Please add an answer with this solution. CAST isn't as nearly efficient.

Comment: @joshuahedlund That works until you have data with times `t > 23:59:59 and t < 24:00:00`. Why deal with poorly specified `BETWEEN` at all? Rather follow David's advice and use: `WHERE dob >= '2011-01-01' AND dob < '2011-02-01'`. Best performance, and it works every time.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, Why do you think so? Elaborate on this please.

Comment: @Green to avoid the cost of conversion and gain the speed of an index on the field as joshuahedlund and Craig Young clarified. It's possible that MySQL optimizes queries like this to be equivalent.

Comment: @joshuahedlund I find that when i use this `SELECT * FROM sales WHERE 
created >= '2020-01-09 00:00:00' 
AND created <= '2020-01-09 11:59:59' 
AND store_id=3` is doesn't select data but when i use this `SELECT * FROM sales WHERE 
DATE(created) >= '2020-01-09 00:00:00' 
AND DATE(created) <= '2020-01-09 11:59:59' 
AND store_id=3` it does return data. the date field is datetime, do you know why that happens?

Answer (score 330):

From the [MySQL-manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

> This is equivalent to the expression
>   (min <= expr AND expr <= max)

Comment: The manual linked in this answer shows that a cast is preferred when comparing DATE and DATETIME objects. So I guess @tiagoinu has the most complete answer in the strictest sense, but both are spot on.

Comment: @jemminger may be because the answer is from *archrival*-postgres guy :P

Comment: In short **between is inclusive**...that is why this answer rocks.

Comment: Old comment, but I wanted to tie this to the specific query.  "BETWEEN" is inclusive, but dates with no time specified pad to 00:00:00.  Comparing on a date range will therefore lose the last day.  Either call DATE(dob) or specify the end of the day.

Comment: they say practice is gold, from my use case it is not inclusive at all, I wonder why this happens with me. I tried and sometimes it works sometimes not. using it on TIME data field.

Answer (score 131):

The problem is that 2011-01-31 really is 2011-01-31 00:00:00. That is the beginning of the day. Everything during the day is not included.

Comment: This really explains what is going on and answers the question.

Comment: After all those years this answer is still the best. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 34):

```
select * from person where dob between '2011-01-01 00:00:00' and '2011-01-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Daniel Hilgarth's answer explains the problem, Guarav provides the quick and easy solution.

Comment: I *think* it worth noting that, this will not include dates at `2011-01-31 23:59:59` but will include those up to `2011-01-31 23:59:58` *the last second of the day is not included* It could be minor but someone will benefit from.

Comment: rahmanisback from MySQL Documentation I can confirm the last second WILL be included since BETWEEN is in both-ways inclusive.
refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Yes, @Felype you're right. I checked this myself in mysql database. It includes also the `23:59:59` in the result. So its both ways inclusive.

Comment: If the `dob` column is a timestamp with sub-second precision, then won't `BETWEEN` still miss events within the final second of the day unless '2011-02-01 00:00:00' is used instead?

Comment: -1. Won't include `2011-01-31 23:59:59.003`. @nitrogen using `2011-02-01 000:00:00` will _incorrectly_ include zero time on 1st February.... Which is why `>=` and `<` should be used instead.

Answer (score 8):

Is the field you are referencing in your query a **Date** type or a **DateTime** type?

A common cause of the behavior you describe is when you use a DateTime type where you really should be using a Date type. That is, unless you really need to know what time someone was born, just use the Date type.

The reason the final day is not being included in your results is the way that the query is assuming the time portion of the dates that you did not specify in your query.

That is: Your query is being interpreted as up to Midnight between 2011-01-30 and 2011-01-31, but the data may have a value sometime later in the day on 2011-01-31.

**Suggestion: Change the field to the Date type if it is a DateTime type.**

Answer (score 7):

Hi this query works for me,

```
select * from person where dob between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Do you have a date field or datetime field?

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from person where DATE(dob) between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'
```

Surprisingly such conversions are solutions to many problems in MySQL.

Comment: Surprisingly, this is exactly what the accepted answer (and several others) said... 2 years before you did.

Answer (score 3):

In MySql between the values are inclusive therefore when you give try to get between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'

it will include from `2011-01-01 00:00:00` upto `2011-01-31 00:00:00`
therefore nothing actually in 2011-01-31 since its time should go from `2011-01-31 00:00:00 ~ 2011-01-31 23:59:59`

For the upper bound you can change to `2011-02-01` then it will get all data upto `2011-01-31 23:59:59`

Answer (score 1):

You can run the query as:

```sql
select * from person where dob between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31 23:59:59'
```

like others pointed out, if your dates are hardcoded.

On the other hand, if the date is in another table, you can add a day and subtract a second (if the dates are saved without the second/time), like:

```sql
select * from person JOIN some_table ... where dob between some_table.initial_date and (some_table.final_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

Avoid doing casts on the `dob` fiels (like in the accepted answer), because that can cause huge performance problems (like not being able to use an index in the `dob` field, assuming there is one). The execution plan may change from `using index condition` to `using where` if you make something like `DATE(dob)` or `CAST(dob AS DATE)`, so be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Set the upper date to date + 1 day, so in your case, set it to 2011-02-01.

Comment: This will _incorrectly_ include zero time on 1st February.... Which is why `BETWEEN` should be ignored; but `>=` and `<` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from person where dob between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31' or dob like' 2011-01-31%'
```

Just add `or <<column>> like "date%"`.