# MySQL - DATE_ADD month interval

Tags: mysql, sql, select, dateadd

I face a problem with the function `DATE_ADD` in MySQL.

My request looks like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydb 
WHERE creationdate BETWEEN "2011-01-01" AND DATE_ADD("2011-01-01", INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
GROUP BY MONTH(creationdate)
```

The problem is that, in the results, -I think- because *June* has only 30 days, the function doesn't work properly as I have the results of the first of *July*.

Is there a way to tell `DATE_ADD` to work well and take the right number of days within a month?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`DATE_ADD` works just fine with different months. The problem is that you are adding six months to `2001-01-01` and July 1st is supposed to be there.

This is what you want to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydb 
WHERE creationdate BETWEEN "2011-01-01" 
                   AND DATE_ADD("2011-01-01", INTERVAL 6 MONTH) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY MONTH(creationdate)
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydb 
WHERE creationdate >= "2011-01-01" 
AND creationdate < DATE_ADD("2011-01-01", INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY MONTH(creationdate)
```

For further learning, take a look at [DATE_ADD documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

*edited to correct syntax

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted :) Thank you, didn't know we could use more than one interval with DATE_ADD.

Comment: btw, "INTERVAL 6 MONTHS" should be "INTERVAL 6 MONTH". Note the lack of the 'S' at the end.

Comment: That's because this is SQL, not your language. It means: INTERVAL AMOUNT TYPE

Answer (score 6):

Well, for me this is the expected result; adding six months to Jan. 1st July.

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD( '2011-01-01', INTERVAL 6 month );
+--------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD( '2011-01-01', INTERVAL 6 month ) |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 2011-07-01                                 | 
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: In fact the desired result for me would be to have "2011-06-30", but don't really know how to get it...

Comment: DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( '2011-01-01', INTERVAL 6 month ), INTERVAL 1 day )

Comment: or you explicitly have to use > and < instead of BETWEEN

Comment: The DATE_SUB works fine, thank you. In fact, i focused on the 6 months interval, and didn't really thjough about removing one day afterwards x(

Answer (score 1):

[`BETWEEN ... AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, `BETWEEN` returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.

The important part here is EQUAL to max., which 1st of July is.

Comment: I know what BETWEEN is, but ni my context, I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand right that you assume that `DATE_ADD("2011-01-01", INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` should give you '2011-06-30' instead of '2011-07-01'? Of course, 2011-01-01 + 6 months is 2011-07-01. You want something like `DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD("2011-01-01", INTERVAL 6 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_ADD` works correctly. 1 January plus 6 months is 1 July, just like 1 January plus 1 month is 1 of February.

Between operation is inclusive. So, you are getting everything up to, and including, 1 July. (see also [MySQL "between" clause not inclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive))

What you need to do is subtract 1 day or use < operator instead of between.

Comment: As the "6" is a dynamic number, I can't use BETWEEN in my request.