# How to add date condition to my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL statement. It works, and I need to add another one condition.
I need to sort it by date. **occurence** - is my date row.

```
SELECT dd.caption, COUNT(t.occurence) 
FROM transaction t 
  INNER JOIN dict_departments dd
    ON dd.id = t.terminal_id
GROUP BY dd.caption
```

How to add this condition:

```
WHERE t.occurence BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

to my query.

Comment: What RDBMS are you on? Many of the relevant functions vary by vendor.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens dbForge Studio for MySql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - DATE\_ADD month interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845604/mysql-date-add-month-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BETWEEN` requires two arguments, a start point and an end point. If your end point is the current time, you have two options:

1. Using `BETWEEN`:

`WHERE t.occurence BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  AND NOW()`

2. Using simple comparison operator:

`WHERE t.occurence >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WHERE t.occurrece BETWEEN current_date() AND dateadd(month,1,current_date())
```

The function *dateadd* is a SQL SERVER function, but the rest of the clause is standard SQL.

Comment: I understand you, but how can I add it to my existing query?

Comment: Use `DATE_ADD` in MySQL ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter dates from 1 month ago till now:

```
WHERE (t.occurrece BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND CURDATE()) = 1
```

or

```
WHERE (t.occurrece BETWEEN ADDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND CURDATE()) = 1
```