# Look up a date between two database fields

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a piece of code which looks up a year between to fields in the database which are year_start & year_end.

And here is my code.

```
  SELECT * from $tableName where '$year' BETWEEN start_year AND end_year; LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Now this seems to work fine except if the year is equal to the end_year value  for example if i am searching for 2002 and the end year value is 2002, then it returns no results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me like you are looking for [MySQL “between” clause not inclusive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive)

Comment: `BETWEEN` should return the endpoint results.  What are the data types and actual contents of `start_year` and `end_year`? Are they DATETIMEs?

Comment: Hi Thanks, no they are just varchars

Comment: In that case you have to `CAST` them

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?, Thanks i just googled it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `start_year` and `end_year` type is

**INT**

```
$sql = '
SELECT *
FROM '.$tableName.'
WHERE TRUE
  AND '.$year.' BETWEEN start_year AND end_year
LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'
;
';
```

**DATE**

```
$sql = '
SELECT *
FROM '.$tableName.'
WHERE TRUE
  AND '.$year.' BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'
;
';
```

**VARCHAR**
to need to cast them

```
$sql = '
SELECT *
FROM '.$tableName.'
WHERE TRUE
  AND '.$year.' BETWEEN
    CAST(start_year AS UNSIGNED) AND CAST(end_year AS UNSIGNED)
LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'
;
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare start_year and end_year before executing the query.

```
// If they're the same,
If start_year == end_year{
  select * from $tableName where '$year' = start_year; LIMIT $start, $limit;
  // more code
}

// if not, use your query
else{
  SELECT * from $tableName where '$year' BETWEEN start_year AND end_year; LIMIT $start, $limit;
  // more code
}
```

Not the prettiest solution but still a nice workaround.