# mysql BETWEEN is exclusive on right for characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, between

Consider this table named `easy_drinks`,

```
+------------------+
| drink_name       |
+------------------+
| Kiss on the Lips |
| Hot Gold         |
| Lone Tree        |
| Greyhound        |
| Indian Summer    |
| Bull Frog        |
| Soda and It      |
| Blackthorn       |
| Blue Moon        |
| Oh My Gosh       |
| Lime Fizz        |
+------------------+
```

A query as such,

```
 select drink_name from easy_drinks where drink_name BETWEEN 'G' and 'O';
```

results in

```
+------------------+
| drink_name       |
+------------------+
| Kiss on the Lips |
| Hot Gold         |
| Lone Tree        |
| Greyhound        |
| Indian Summer    |
| Lime Fizz        |
+------------------+
```

drink names starting with `O` are not included in the result. But as per the manual [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

> expr BETWEEN min AND max
>
> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is **less than or equal
>   to max**, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.
>   If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN >returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Why is the query giving such results?

I have been through [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive) that explain the behaviour for Timestamp and Date. What is the reason in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Don't use BETWEEN for strings

where drink_name >= 'G' and drink_name < 'P';

### Why?

The O is effectivly expanded with trailing spaces to match the column. So

```
'O                  '
```

is before

```
'Oh My Gosh'
```

So you'd need

```
where drink_name BETWEEN 'G' and 'OZ';
```

If you have a drink called `Ozymandias` then this won't work. So:

```
where drink_name BETWEEN 'G' and 'OZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ';
```

But, can we can safely assume that there is no drink called `P` and many spaces?
This is not understandable.

```
select drink_name from easy_drinks
where drink_name BETWEEN 'G' and 'P';
```

The obvious choice might be to compare only first letters using [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```
select drink_name from easy_drinks
where LEFT(drink_name, 1) BETWEEN 'G' and 'O';
```

But this will prevent used of any index on drink_name.

Comment: Also `where drink_name >= 'G' and drink_name < 'P'`

Comment: @ypercube: was going to say that but got carried away :)

Comment: What I'm not sure is how case sensitivity affects these variations.

Comment: That would be a collation issue. I work case insensitive almost always

Answer (score 2):

Here's [an easier way to spot what's going on](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/010da/6):

```
select drink_name, drink_name >='G', drink_name <='O'
from easy_drinks
order by 1;
```

Key results are:

- `Greyhound` is >= 'G'
- `Oh My Gosh` is **not** <= 'O'

It makes sense once you think about it. In a dictionary, a single O entry is always the first item in letter O.

You probably want [something like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/010da/9):

```
select drink_name
from easy_drinks
where SUBSTRING(drink_name, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'G' and 'O';
```

**Edit:**

I completely forgot about `LEFT(drink_name, 1)`, which is a handy shorcut for `SUBSTRING(drink_name, 1, 1)`.

Comment: LEFT also means "don't use any index" though.