# MySQL How to select a date record between the min and max

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have four dates, for example:

- 1/1/2018
- 2/5/2018
- 4/8/2018
- 9/9/2018

I want to 'select' a date in between the min and max. Either the 2/5/2018 record or the 4/8/2018 record ONLY.

I think I'm close, but this query returns ALL the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM RUBERIC R  
WHERE R.SCHOOLID = 75 
AND R.TEACHERID = 610 
AND R.OBSERVED = 'Observed Classroom' 
AND R.DATE BETWEEN 
(SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM RUBERIC WHERE R.SCHOOLID = 75 
AND R.TEACHERID = 610 AND R.OBSERVED = 'Observed Classroom' )
AND
(SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM RUBERIC WHERE R.SCHOOLID = 75 
AND R.TEACHERID = 610 AND R.OBSERVED = 'Observed Classroom' )
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BETWEEN` includes the end points.  Presumably, you want to exclude them:

```
SELECT R.*
FROM RUBERIC R  
WHERE R.SCHOOLID = 75 AND
      R.OBSERVED = 'Observed Classroom' AND
      R.DATE > (SELECT MIN(R2.DATE) FROM RUBERIC R2 WHERE R2.SCHOOLID = 75 
AND R2.TEACHERID = 610 AND R2.OBSERVED = 'Observed Classroom'
               ) AND
      R.DATE < (SELECT MAX(R2.DATE) FROM RUBERIC R2 WHERE R2.SCHOOLID = 75 
AND R2.TEACHERID = 610 AND R2.OBSERVED = 'Observed Classroom'
               );
```

Also, your query is -- inadvertently -- a correlated subquery.  The table alias `R` refers to the rows in the main query, not the subquery.  You should always define table aliases and always use them, but use them properly.  (Note all the `R2`s in the subqueries in this version.)

In general, I strongly discourage anyone from using `BETWEEN` with date or date/times.  This is not a problem in your case, but the time component can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  The table aliases make sense.  This removed the MIN and MAX records.  Now, I'm trying to get it to select ONE of the 2 'middle' records.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that `BETWEEN` is inclusive.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080937/9392034).

Answer (score 0):

Your BETWEEN condtition doesn't change anything on the result set, since MIN and MAX will be included. You need to split the BETWEEN condition into `<` and `>` conditions. But in order to not duplicate the conditions on SCHOOLID, TEACHERID and OBSERVED, I would first select the min and max date in a subquery and then join the table to it.

```
SELECT R.*
FROM (
    SELECT SCHOOLID, TEACHERID, OBSERVED, MIN(DATE) AS MIN_DATE, MAX(DATE) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM RUBERIC
    WHERE SCHOOLID  = 75 
      AND TEACHERID = 610 
      AND OBSERVED  = 'Observed Classroom'
) X
JOIN RUBERIC R
  ON  R.SCHOOLID  = X.SCHOOLID
  AND R.TEACHERID = X.TEACHERID
  AND R.OBSERVED  = X.OBSERVED
  AND R.DATE      > X.MIN_DATE
  AND R.DATE      < X.MAX_DATE
```

If you need to select "any" one of the rows, just add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query.