# MySQL SP: Get Records from the last 4 Months, Month and Year Given

Tags: mysql

I am creating a *Stored Procedure* to get all the records from the previous 4 months, given the month and year variables.

The datetime format of `etimestamp` column is *12/30/2020 12:000:00 AM*.

If inMonth >= 4, this statement will work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE Month(etimestamp) in (inMonth , inMonth - 1, inMonth - 2, inMonth - 3) AND
Year(etimestamp) = inYear
```

However, this won't work if inMonth is not >= 4.

I want a query that will also work for the last year.

*For example:*
**inMonth = 2** AND **inYear = 2020**

*Expected Output Records:*

- February 2020
- January 2020
- **December 2019**
- **November 2019**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE etimestamp between now() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH and now()
```

Comment: and you can change now() to STR_TO_DATE('01,imonth,inyear','%d,%m,%Y') to get data within the previous 4 months of the variable inyear and inmonth

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mr Syhd. I obtained the idea to get started. I added modifications to make clause **inclusive**. This is my final query:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (STR_TO_DATE('01, inMonth, inYear','%d, %m, %Y') - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) <= etimestamp AND etimestamp <= (STR_TO_DATE('01, inMonth, inYear', '%d, %m, %Y') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Comment: @JonnelVeXuZDorotan your welcome, yeah you're right, i forgot about the inclusiveness

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, @Mr Syhd for the answer. I obtained the idea to get started. I added modifications to your answer to make the clause inclusive.

This is now my final query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01, ', inMonth, ', ', inYear),'%d, %m, %Y') - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) <= etimestamp AND
    etimestamp <= (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01, ', inMonth, ', ', inYear),'%d, %m, %Y') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Helpful Link: [MySQL “between” clause not inclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive)